# jquery file browse adding and removing but not able to take file from other input tags except first

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, file

### I want to apply a logic from which I can use give new generated class to new added element.

I want that whenever I click on `Add Another`, it will add new file browse and I can select different images from that. The first image should always be primary and others will be secondary.
When I click on remove link, corresponding file browse and dropdown should be removed.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".browse").click(function(){
        $(".myfile").click(); 
    });

    $(".myfile").on('change', function() { 
        $(".path").val(this.files[0].name); 
    });

    $(".add").click(function(){
        $("form").append("<div>"+$("form div:first-child").html()+"<br>"+"</div>"); 
    });

    $(".remove").click(function(){
        $("form div:last-child").remove(); 
    });
});
```

```css
.main{
    width: 100%;
}

.sub1{
    border: 2px solid #808080;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.sub2{
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #808080;  
}


.child1{
    width: 20%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
}

.child2{
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
}

.add{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.upload1{
    display: none;
}

.browse{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.browsebut{
    margin-left: 16px;
}

.myf{
    position: absolute;     
}




/* position: absolute;
    opacity: 5;
    top: 74px;
    display: -webkit-box; */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Browse</title>
    <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="main">
        <div class="sub1">
            <p>Property Image</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub2">
            <div class="child1">
                <p>Property Image</p>
            </div>
            <div class="child2">

               
                    <form>
                        <div class="upload">
                            <input type="text" name="path" class="path" value="no file selected">

                            <div id="browse" class="browse"><span class="browsebut">Browse</span></div>
                            <div class="myf"> 
                                <label for="myfile"></label>
                                <input type="file" class="myfile" name="myfile" accept="image/*" hidden >
                            </div>
                            <select id="img">
                                <option value="1">primary</option>
                                <option value="1">secondaryimg</option>
                            </select>

                            <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                        </div>        
                
                    </form>
                
                    
                
                <div class="add">
                    <p>Add Another</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>[enter image description here][1]

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're trying to achieve, need to use [event delegates](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). When new elements are dynamically added, the handlers added by your original jQuery code is only aware of the *first* row's elements, which is why none of the other row elements seemed to work after adding additional rows.

There were a couple of corrections applied:

1. For the row elements, I removed all `id` attributes, for these need to be unique in the document.
2. Both select options had `value="1"`, so I set the `secondaryimg` option to `value="2"`
3. Removed the unused `label` tag.

Other:

1. Used `placeholder` with the first input to show the `no file selected` text.
2. See the `.add` handler for the handling to set the `select` option to `secondaryimg`
3. The `remove` event handler does not allow the primary (first element) to be removed. (feel free to eliminate the condition wrapping `remove()` if not needed)
4. Having repeated elements with the same `name` is why only the first entry is retrieved. Now that there will be one or more rows, the name attributes for `path`, `myfile` and the `select` *all* need the array syntax, so that whenever you submit, you can easily iterate the list. The `path` input `name` attribute changes to `name="path[]"`. The `myfile` input `name` attribute changes to `name="myfile[]"`, and the select did not have a name attribute, so I used `name="imgOpt[]"`, feel free to rename as desired. At submit, the iteration of `path[0]`, `myfile[0]`, and `imgOpt[0]` all refer to the first row. Simply increase the index for the other rows.
5. See the jquery code comments for the updated handling.

Try the runnable example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Browse button event delegate
    $('form').on('click', '.browse', function(){
        // Fire click for myfile input on the SAME row
        $(this).next().find('input').click(); 
    });

    // Myfile change event delegate
    $('form').on('change', '.myfile', function() {
        // Copy the image to the path input on the SAME row.
        $(this).parent().siblings().first().val(this.files[0].name); 
    });

    $(".add").click(function(){
        $("form").append("<div>"+$("form div:first-child").html()+"<br>"+"</div>");
         // Set the added select to the 2nd (secondaryimg) option.
        $('select').last().val(2);
    });

    // Anchor tag event delegate
    $("form").on('click', 'a.remove', function() {
        if (!$(this).is($('a')[0])) { // Don't remove the first primary anchor tag?
            $(this).parent().remove();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.main{
    width: 100%;
}

.sub1{
    border: 2px solid #808080;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.sub2{
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #808080;  
}


.child1{
    width: 20%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
}

.child2{
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
}

.add{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.upload1{
    display: none;
}

.browse{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.browsebut{
    margin-left: 16px;
}

.myf{
    position: absolute;     
}

/* position: absolute;
    opacity: 5;
    top: 74px;
    display: -webkit-box; */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Browse</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="main">
        <div class="sub1">
            <p>Property Image</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub2">
            <div class="child1">
                <p>Property Image</p>
            </div>
            <div class="child2">
                <form>
                    <div class="upload">
                        <input type="text" name="path[]" class="path" 
                               placeholder="no file selected" value="">

                        <div class="browse">
                            <span class="browsebut">Browse</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="myf"> 
                            <input type="file" class="myfile" 
                                   name="myfile[]" accept="image/*" hidden>
                        </div>
                        <select name="imgOpt[]">
                            <option value="1">primary</option>
                            <option value="2">secondaryimg</option>
                        </select>
                        <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                    </div>        
                </form>
                <div class="add">
                    <p>Add Another</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```